# Ошибка загрузки поставщиков из файла kdenlive rendersources.xml

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Ubuntu 16.04 x64 Kdenlive 15.12.3

Settings->Download new render profiles...

ошибка загрузки поставщиков из файла: https://kdenlive.org/data/rendersources.xml

Как исправить ситуацию?

Comment: оффтоп же, нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так (с точностью до путей): `sed -i -re 's!(^ProvidersUrl=).*!\1http://download.kde.org/ocs/providers.xml!' /etc/xdg/kdenlive_renderprofiles.knsrc`

Но особого смысла не имеет, т.к. там пока всего [один таковой](https://store.kde.org/p/1164337).